# C# ListView right align will hide when column width is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, text

Is there a way to fix this or do i have to align the GridViewColumn to left or center?
For Example i have a column that shows a file size in MB and i have it aligned to the right, 
but if i change the width of the column the text in the column disappears.

```
    <ListView Name="myLV" SelectionMode="Single" ItemcontainerStyle="{DynamicResource lvis}" ItemSource="{Binding mySource}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" local:MainWindow.SortName="Model.filename">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding DisplayFilename}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Filesize" local:MainWindow.SortName="Model.FileSize">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding DisplayFileSize}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Width="123" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

My Solution:

```
    <ListView Name="myLV" SelectionMode="Single" ItemcontainerStyle="{DynamicResource lvis}" ItemSource="{Binding mySource}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" local:MainWindow.SortName="Model.filename" width="Auto">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding DisplayFilename}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Filesize" local:MainWindow.SortName="Model.FileSize" width="Auto">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding DisplayFileSize}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The GridViewColumn has now a Auto width and the width in the Textblock was deleted.
Now the text wont disappear immadiately. it only begins to disappear when the space has no room left.

Comment: Can you show us some code? And maybe a little more info?